# PHP Radio button mysql query

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I have 4 different MySQL query's and I want to be able to choose which one is used based on which radio button is clicked. I was wondering what would be the best way to do this?

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="query1" value="">Rating<br>
<input type="radio" name="query2" value="">Genre<br>
<input type="radio" name="query3" value="">Year<br>
<input type="radio" name="query4" value="">Rating,Genre,Year
</form>
```

Do I store the query's on individual php pages and then call them using the radio button or ....?

The query's select movie info from a database and then order them by either rating, year, genre or all three.

Comment: You can use `isset()` with functions, and do it all inside one page if you want.

Comment: Gee, should I have posted that as an answer? I did get an upvote ^ *"No Fred, not without a graphical representation, you silly Sam."*

Comment: By the way, you're working too hard with those radio buttons.

Comment: so it would do if the radio button is set 1 then do this query1 if set 2 do query2

Comment: This is far too broad but that's basically it; *sure*. If I put in an answer, it could grow into even more comments. So, you'll need to post your SQL/PHP, or take it up with the person who has given you an "answer" below.

Comment: what I am tring to do is recreate the same type of thing they have on say an ebay or Amazon page, where you can change the search on the current page

Comment: Lordie, *the plot thickens* already. Now this is by far, way too broad a question.

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: is it broad? All I am asking is how to use a radio button so that when it is clicked it runs a query. It must not be as easy as I think it is

Comment: I've posted an answer for you below that you can base yourself on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set all your radio buttons to hold the same name attribute but with different values, then upon submit and choosing the desired radio button, query for what is matched.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(!isset($_POST['query'])){
    echo "You chose nothing";
    }

    if($_POST['query'] == "Rating"){
    // query for Rating
        echo "Rating";
    }

    if($_POST['query'] == "Genre"){
    // query for Genre
        echo "Genre";
    }

    if($_POST['query'] == "Year"){
    // query for Year
        echo "Year";
    }

    if($_POST['query'] == "Rating,Genre,Year"){
    // query for Rating,Genre,Year
        echo "Rating,Genre,Year";
    }

} // brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="query" value="Rating">Rating<br>
<input type="radio" name="query" value="Genre">Genre<br>
<input type="radio" name="query" value="Year">Year<br>
<input type="radio" name="query" value="Rating,Genre,Year">Rating,Genre,Year
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit query">
</form>
```

---

- This is at best, a basic example.
- When using database-related code, remember to use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a go now and see if I can get it working, I will let you know how thing go, again Thanks

Comment: @McNoodles **Nota:** This will work. If it doesn't, then it would have been because of how you setup your queries. That, would be another question. You basically put your related queries inside `// query for Rating` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons must have same name.

Without a method="post" the `<form>` method will be "get" so the PHP would use `$_GET` not `$_POST`

```
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="query" value="1">Rating<br>
<input type="radio" name="query" value="2">Genre<br>
<input type="radio" name="query" value="3">Year<br>
<input type="radio" name="query" value="4">Rating,Genre,Year
</form>
```

I am not a big fan of using IF ELSE branching structures and avoid them whenever possible.

I prefer passing integer values to be used in arrays.

PHP

```
$q = intval($_GET['query']);
```

The `intval()` will return a zero if `($_GET['query']` return no value.

```
$queries = array(
0 => $query4,
1 => $query1,
2 => $query2,
3 => $query3,
4 => $query4);

$sql = $queries[$q];
```